# Disjoint $k$ Increasing Subsequences

Tags: algorithms, longest-common-substring

Given a permutation $P$ and an integer $k$, we need to devise an algorithm which finds the $k$ disjoint increasing subsequences (say $L_1,L_2\ldots, L_k$) such that the sum total of their lengths (say $S_k$) is maximum is over any choice of $k$ disjoint increasing subsequences from a permutation $P$. For simplicity, one can assume that $k$ is atmost than the length of the longest decreasing subsequence.

For example consider $P=[4,1,2,7,5,6,3]$

Here if $k=1$, then longest increasing subsequence is of length 4 (i.e $S_1=4$) which corresponds to the subsequence [1,2,5,6]

Here if $k=2$, then the maximum length of two disjoint increasing subsequences is 6 (i.e $S_2=6$) which corresponds to the two disjoint increasing subsequences [1,2,3] and [4,5,6].

Possibly simple question

**Is there an $O(n $poly log $n)$ algorithm which can keep track of the values $S_1,S_2\ldots,S_k$** under insertions?

Possibly harder question

**Is there an $O(n $poly log $n)$ algorithm which can keep track of the values as well as the increasing subsequences corresponding to $S_1,S_2\ldots,S_k$** under insertions?

Comment: Is it possible to compute $S_2$ in $o(n^2)$ time? Is it possible to compute $S_3$ in $O(n^2)$ time?

Comment: What are the best algorithms you have been able to find so far?  What's the fastest you know how to solve this in the static case, where there is only a single value of $P,k$?